# Redis snapshots uses too much ram

Tags: java, windows, redis, operating-system

I have a redis server that keeps almost 1500000 keys under a huge traffic (500 requests per second, almost 50 write operation per request), on Windows Server 2008 R2 OS. It works good with very low response times. However, when it starts the snapshot process, it keeps increasing ram usage then, couple of minutes later, goes back to normal.

Here is the screen shot when it happens :

[image: Memory Usage]

And here is the redis snapshot configuration at conf file :

```
save 900 1
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
```

Here is the memory info from redis client :

[image: Cli Info]

Is this normal ? If not, how can I fix this ?

Comment: This is normal - snapshotting, even in the Windows fork, requires additional memory and up to **twice** the size of the dataset in the worst case scenario.

Comment: Widows will use as much resources as possible. You paid for the RAM. Why do you complain, that the OS makes use of it?

Comment: Why do I complain, because I have a million key for now, what is going to happen when it is 100 million ? I just wanna correct something, if it is designed wrong, in early period. This is the main objective of my question.

Comment: If you want to see how your system behaves when scaled by a factor of 100, set up a test system. The system can fail for an unlimited number of reasons. Running out if RAM is likely not one of them. After all, RAM is just a performance optimization in systems that implement virtual memory management.